# Como recuperar campos dinâmicos C# para SQL

Tags: c#, sql, foreach, campos

Estou fazendo um site em ASP que possui campos dinâmicos em js:

```js
a = 0;
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    a++;
    return '<div class="container bg-light p-3 mb-2"><div class="form-group row justify-content-center">'+
        '<div class="col-sm-1"> <label ID = "lblPag_'+a+'" class="col-form-label" >Páginas:</label ></div>' +
        '<div class="col-sm-1">' +
            '<input name = "txtPag' + a + '" type="text" value = "' + value + '"  class="form-control"/> </div>' +
        '<div class="col-sm-1">' +
            '<label ID="lblPublique' + a + '" class="col-form-label">até</label></div>' +
        '<div class="col-sm-1">' +
            '<input name = "txtPagF' + a + '" type="text" value = "' + value + '"  class="form-control"/> </div>' +
        '<div class="col-sm-1">' +
            '<label ID="lblPublique'+a+'" class="col-form-label">Descrição:</label></div>' +
        '<div class="col-sm-2">' +
            '<input name = "txtDesc' + a + '" type="text" value = "' + value + '"class="form-control"/> </div></div>' +
        '<div class="form-group row justify-content-center">' +
            '<div class="col-sm-1">' +
                '<label ID="lblPublique' + a + '" class="col-form-label">Autor:</label></div>' +
            '<div class="col-sm-2">' +
                '<input name = "txtAutor' + a + '" type="text" value = "' + value + '"  class="form-control"/> </div>' +
            '<div class="col-sm-4">' +
                '<input type="file" name="fileUp'+a+' value="'+value+'"></div>' +
            '<div class="col-sm-1">' +
                '<input type="button" value="Remover" class="btn btn-danger" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" /></div></div></div>'
}
function AddTextBox() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
    document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
}

function RemoveTextBox() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer");
    if (ele.lastChild) {
        ele.removeChild(ele.lastChild);
    }
}

function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() {
    var values = eval('<%=Values%>');
    if (values != null) {
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox(values[i]) + "</div>";
        }
        document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;
    }
}
window.onload = RecreateDynamicTextboxes;
```

E salva os campos no SQL, mas eu precisaria salvar todos os campos que podem ser adicionados, ou seja, vários txtN.Text. Como poderia ser feito? Estou confusa se uso list ou algum outro comando.
CS:

```
protected void btnSalvar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cnx = new Conexao();
        var con = cnx.ConexaoBD();
        var XX = @"DECLARE @ID INT INSERT INTO POLIS_RI_PUBLICACAO(NOME, CATEGORIA) VALUES('"+txtDesc.Text+"', '"+dpdCategoria.Text+"') SET @ID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()) INSERT INTO POLIS_RI_ARTIGO(IDPUB, PGINI, PGFIN, NOMEAUTOR) VALUES(@ID, '"+txtPag.Text+"', '"+txtPag1.Text+"', '"+txtAutor.Text+"')";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(XX, con);
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    }
```

Comment: Você precisa de um loop for(i = 0; i <=A;i++){  var ele = document.getElementById("txtDesc.Text" + i);} .... onde seu A é igual a sua variável (a = 0;)... assim você teria a lista de campos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maisa, pelo que pude entender do seu codigo, você está querendo armazenar os campos que são criados dinamicamente através de colunas.
Porém eu sugiro que você faça a administração desses campos na vertical, usando relacionamentos.
Nesse modelo horizontal criando colunas para cada campo, uma hora sua tabela ficará insustentavel.

Exemplo:
Crie uma tabela que irá armazenar os campos:

ID | NomeCampo

- 1 | PagIni
- 2 | PagInfo
- 3 | Autor

Depois crie uma tabela que irá armazenar o valor de cada campo com uma chave estrangeira apontando para a tabela anterior.

Campo_Id | Valor

- 1 | Home.html
- 2 | FAQ.html
- 3 | Paulo Coelho
- 3 | Clarisse Lispector

Depois para saber quais campos foram adicionados e os valores atribuidos a esse campo você só precisa fazerm um join entre as tabelas.
Se ainda sim, quiser que o nome do campo fique em colunas e os valores em linhas, você pode aplicar um pivot table no sql quando realizar sua consulta.